# Laravel show all links in paginator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Since Laravel 5.7, the paginator `links()` method shows only a reduced number of pages when called. The number of links can be customized using the `onEachSide($count)` method.

```
‹‹ ‹ 1 2 ... 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 ... 102 103 › ››
```

I want to display every page in order to make a page selector dropdown, using a html `<select>`.

Calling `onEachSide(9999)` does work, but it looks flimsy, and may break on high page counts that the app i'm writing could reach.

What would be the clean way to get all the page links ?

EDIT: I am using a custom view, which looks like the following :

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <li class="disabled">&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</li>
            <li class="disabled">&lsaquo;</li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->toArray()['first_page_url'] }}">&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}">&lsaquo;</a></li>
        @endif

        {{--Pagination Elements --}}
        @foreach ($elements as $element)
            @if (is_string($element))
                <li class="disabled"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
            @endif

            @if (is_array($element))
                @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                    @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                        <li class="active"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                    @else
                        <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach

        {{-- Next Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}">&rsaquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}">&rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a></li>
        @else
            <li class="disabled">&rsaquo;</li>
            <li class="disabled"><span>&rsaquo;&rsaquo;</li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endif
```

The `$elements` variable seems to already have the extra pages removed, however.

Comment: Why don't you use the information of how many pages there are to count back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paginator uses the [bootstrap-4 blade view](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/bootstrap-4.blade.php) to render the page. This view always implements the tripple dots.
You could create a custom view that renders all pagination pages without any tripple dot items and pass this view as the first parameter to the [links function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L76).

---

**Update:** The view you are using is exactly the same as the one build in to Laravel. You shouldn't use the `$element` variable as this gets windowed with tripple dot elements.

You should use the pagination lastpage variable and loop over all pages yourself. For example, like this:

```
{{-- Pagination Elements --}}
@for ($page = 1; $page <= $paginator->lastPage(); $page++)
    @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
        <li class="active"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
    @else
        <li><a href="{{ $paginator->url($page) }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I already use a custom view, which I added in the question text. My bad for not putting it here in the first place.